# геттеры и сеттеры

Tags: javascript

Возникла проблема при изучении геттеров и сеттеров. Как я понял, они работают так же как и в Java, но почему то объект не меняется. Вывод программы berlin, хотя по логике вещей должно быть warsaw

```
let place = {
    _city: 'berlin',
    getCity : () => {
        return this._city
    },
    setCity : (city) => {
        this._city = city
    }}

place.getCity()
place.setCity('warsaw')
console.log(place._city)
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions#u-strelochnyh-funktsiy-net-this

Comment: И это к вас не геттеры/сеттеры в обычном понимании этих теоминов в JS, а просто методы объекта

Comment: @AlexeyTen пока да

Comment: проблема в стрелочной функции, замени ее на обычную и проблема исчезнет. Так же если делать настоящие геттеры и сеттеры - то проблема даже не возникла бы